# Angular (2+) : Template reference on non-component

Tags: angular

Considering the following template, my custom directive "scrollEffect" is provided two template references as @Input:

- a ref to a Component (pageContent)
- a ref to an element (inflowTokensaleJoin)

The component is properly referenced. However, the plain element isn't. Can't we target components, directives and plain dom elements? If so, my code is wrong and cannot see why.

**welcome.html**

```
<ion-content #pageContent>
  <div [scrollEffect]="showFixedToolbarFrom" [scrollContent]="pageContent" [siblingComponent]="inflowTokensaleJoin" class="join fixed">

    ...

    <div #inflowTokensaleJoin *ngIf="!(icoService.isICOEnded()) && (icoStartDate$ | async) > 0" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end"

    ...
</ion-content>
```

**scroll-effect.ts**

```
@Input('siblingComponent') siblingComponent: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  if (this.siblingComponent) {
    console.log('sibling found');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, found my mistake.

I'm using an async *ngIf which causes the one-shot template reference `siblingComponent` (equivalent to @ViewChild) to be evaluated before the async condition is filled. It then runs before the element is attached to the DOM.

To fix this: we must know that template refs are (behind the scenes) a @ViewChild. It runs as the component initializes.

There's the @ViewChildren which doesn't return an ElementRef but a QueryList. The QueryList is kept up-to-date during the entire life of the component (it's more resource intensive, but meant for this kind of situations). I've therefore added the following to the parent component:

```
@ViewChildren('inflowTokensaleJoin') siblingQuery: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

`@ViewChildren` provides a query - and it's refreshed every time to zone is updated. Meaning that whenever I need the sibling element, the following code can be run to get the query's results at that moment (vs. at viewInit time):

```
        const siblings =
          this.siblingQuery &&
          this.siblingQuery.toArray &&
          this.siblingQuery.toArray();

        const sibling =
          siblings && siblings[0] && siblings[0].nativeElement;

        if (sibling) {
          scrollTop > this.config.from ? this.showMe() : this.hideMe();
        }
```